# Find 10 nearest points from an array of coordinates for each coordinate in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an array

```
var poses = arrayOf<Array<Double>>()
```

That I populate using a loop.

The output looks something like this:

```
poses.forEach {
        println(Arrays.toString(it))
    }
```

```
[-71.42510166478651, 106.43593221597114]
[104.46430594348055, 78.62761919208839]
[100.27031925094859, 79.65568893000942]
[311.2433803626159, 233.67219485640456]
[330.3015877764689, -114.9000129699181]
[34.76986782382592, -383.71914014833436]
[355.477931403836, -173.29388985868835]
[322.72821807215564, -45.99138725647516]
...
```

Is there an efficient way to find 10 nearest points from this list for each coordinate? 
For example:
Find 10 nearest points for **[-71.42510166478651, 106.43593221597114]**, then **[104.46430594348055, 78.62761919208839]** and so on.
I tried looking into numpy-like libraries for Kotlin but seeing as though I'm new to the language I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I dunno about the *most* efficient way, but if you're OK with O(n^2 log n), `arr.map { point -> arr.sortedBy { distance(point, it) }.take(10) }`

Comment: I suspect you could do better performance by either partitioning instead of full-fledged sorting (knocks it down to O(kn^2)), or pre-computing the distance matrix, or some kind of fancy graph-partitioning or clustering approach.

Comment: I tried your first comment, it says that "distance"  is an unresolved reference.

Comment: I've thought about using the clustering approach, I'm just not sure how I'd go about implementing it sadly.

Comment: You can replace `distance(point, it)` with `(point[0] - it[0]).pow(2) + (point[1] - it[1]).pow(2)`.

Comment: If you careful about sorting ( e.g. some radix sort type that is `O( log n)` ) you may be able to pull this off in `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a distance function with the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). (This [GeeksforGeeks page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-calculate-distance-two-points/) might be helpful too.)

You could also use a data class for the points, instead of using an array with two double values. The code below uses the approach that [Mateen Ulhaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365102/mateen-ulhaq) suggested in his comment, with two modifications:

1. The addition of "point to" lets us create a map from a point to the ten nearest points (so we know which point the ten points are related to).
2. The call to ".drop(1)" before ".take(10)" keeps the point itself out of its list (since the distance to itself is 0).

This code uses a list of points, determines the nearest points and prints them for each point:

```
fun main() {
    val poses = listOf(
        Point(-71.42510166478651, 106.43593221597114),
        Point(104.46430594348055, 78.62761919208839),
        Point(100.27031925094859, 79.65568893000942),
        Point(311.2433803626159, 233.67219485640456),
        Point(330.3015877764689, -114.9000129699181),
        Point(34.76986782382592, -383.71914014833436),
        Point(355.477931403836, -173.29388985868835),
        Point(322.72821807215564, -45.99138725647516)
    )

    val nearestPoints = poses.map {
        point -> point to poses.sortedBy { point.distance(it) }.drop(1).take(10)
    }

    println("Nearest points:")
    nearestPoints.forEach {
        println("${it.first} is closest to ${it.second}")
    }
}

data class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double) {
    fun distance(that: Point): Double {
        val distanceX = this.x - that.x
        val distanceY = this.y - that.y

        return sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the points are evenly (or almost evenly) distributed in some area, I suggest dividing them into rectangular chunks with size `area.size.x / poses.size * 10` by `area.size.y / poses.size * 10`.

Then to find the nearest points for any point, you only need to check neighboring chunks. Since points are evenly distributed, you can find the nearest points for all points in `O(kn)` where `n` is a number of points and `k = 10`.

---

If the points are not guaranteed to be evenly (or almost evenly) distributed, you have to divide the area into several chunks and then recursively repeat the same process for each chunk until all the sub-chunks contain at most `x` points. (It's hard to tell what is optimal `x` and optimal count of sub-chunks per chunk, you need to do some research to find it out).

Then you can find the nearest points for any point, just as you did with evenly distributed points.

---

A few tricks to improve performance:

1. Use `distanceSquared` instead of `distance`. Here is how you can implement `distanceSquared`:

```
fun Point.distanceSquared(other: Point) = (x - other.x).squared() + (y - other.y).squared()

typealias Point = Array<Double>

val Point.x get() = this[0]
val Point.y get() = this[1]

fun Double.squared() = this * this
```

2. Use `PriorityQueue<Point>(10, compareBy { -it.distanceSquared(destination) })` to store nearest points, and `offer(point, 10)` to add points to it:

```
fun <E : Any> PriorityQueue<E>.offer(element: E, maxSize: Int) {
    if (size < maxSize) offer(element)
    else if (compare(element, peek()) > 0) {
        poll()
        offer(element)
    }
}

// if `comparator()` returns `null` queue uses naturalOrder and `E` is `Comparable<E>`
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <E : Any> PriorityQueue<E>.compare(o1: E, o2: E) =
    comparator()?.compare(o1, o2) ?: (o1 as Comparable<E>).compareTo(o2)
```

3. Divide your points into several groups and run the calculation for each group in a separate thread. It will let your program to use all available cores.